# What does N[1][i] do if N is an array and N[1][i] is inside a for loop? I am having trouble understanding

Tags: python, arrays, string, append

So I was looking at some python code and came across this piece of code: It supposedly scans for all instances of a number in a string, but I don't really get it. Here is my code:

```
inp = open("socdist1.in").read().strip().split()

print(inp)

n = int(inp[0])

cow_places = []
for i in range(n):
    if (inp[1][i] == "1"):
        cow_places.append(i);
print(cow_places)
```

Comment: Hey welcome to the SO! What have you researched in this regard and specifically what is troubling you?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what the N[1][i] == '1' does, I'm confused because I saw this in a tutorial video and the guy used it to scan a string inside an array for the number 1.

Comment: We can only answer you precisely if you can provide the contents of `socdist.in`.

Comment: It does exactly what you just said! It actually searches if the specified index has a value `'1'`

Comment: ['14', '10001001000010']
[0, 4, 7, 12]

Comment: those are the results of the code, socdist1.in is

Comment: 14
10001001000010

Comment: Okay thanks hamza, but what if I did N[0][i] or N[2][i]? what would it do then?

Comment: `N[1][i]` is a combination of two things: `N[1]` and `[i]`. `N[1]` accesses the element with index 1 of your array `N`. And applying `[i]` on _that_ gets the thing at index `i`. I am assuming that `N[1]` is a string, so `N[1][i]`  looks at the character at index `i`. And since `i` is within your for loop, you are looking at each character index `i` from `0` to `n` (that’s what `range(n)` does).

Comment: @RyanDing Awesome, so inp[1] is to access  the second string in socdist.1 which is `'10001001000010'`. `inp[1][i] will gain us access of individual character inside of the string. For example, `inp[1][0]` will return `'1'`.

Comment: Okay, thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp = [14, '10001001000010'] #14 is the length of the string '10001001000010'

print(inp[1]) #outputs '10001001000010'
print(inp[1][0]) #outputs '1'
print(inp[1][2]) #outputs '0'

for i in range(inp[0]): #inp[0] is the length of the string
    print(inp[1][i]) #outputs the i-th character in '10001001000010'
```

The for loop output is as follows:

```
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Poke, Navaneeth Reddy and Hamza for answering my question
For people that are interested, the answer is that N[1][i] is part of two things: N[1] part is the 1st place of the array, and the N[i] scans that part for the thing you are looking for.